Colcon build generates a ros.catkin file
I generated urdf files from solidworks but since it generates the package for ROS1 I made changes to the CMake and package.xml files myself. Now, on colcon build the package is generated as ros.catkin.
home@ROG:~/ros2_ws$ colcon list
kr_10_r1100_2_urdf  src/kr_10_r1100_2_urdf  (ros.catkin)
CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(kr_10_r1100_2_urdf)

# Find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED)
find_package(urdf REQUIRED)
find_package(xacro REQUIRED)

# Install the URDF file
install(DIRECTORY urdf/
  DESTINATION share/${PROJECT_NAME}/urdf
)

ament_package()

package.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>kr_10_r1100_2_urdf</name>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <description>
    <p>URDF Description package for KR_10_R1100-2_URDF</p>
    <p>This package contains configuration data, 3D models, and launch files
    for the KR_10_R1100-2_URDF robot.</p>
  </description>
  <author>Ritabrata Chakraborty</author>
  <maintainer email="ritabrata@email.com">Ritabrata Chakraborty</maintainer>
  <license>BSD</license>

  <!-- Build tool and dependencies -->
  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>

  <!-- Build dependencies -->
  <build_depend>message_generation</build_depend>
  <build_depend>rclcpp</build_depend>
  <build_depend>std_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>geometry_msgs</build_depend>
  <build_depend>urdf</build_depend>
  <build_depend>xacro</build_depend>

  <!-- Run dependencies -->
  <exec_depend>rclcpp</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>std_msgs</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>geometry_msgs</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>urdf</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>xacro</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>message_runtime</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>robot_state_publisher</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>rviz2</exec_depend> <!-- Use rviz2 for ROS 2 -->
  <exec_depend>joint_state_publisher</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>joint_state_publisher_gui</exec_depend>
  <exec_depend>gazebo_ros_pkgs</exec_depend> <!-- Use gazebo_ros_pkgs for ROS 2 -->
  <exec_depend>moveit_commander</exec_depend> <!-- For MoveIt2 -->

  <!-- Build export dependencies (similar to build_depend but for exporting) -->
  <build_export_depend>rclcpp</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>std_msgs</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>geometry_msgs</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>urdf</build_export_depend>
  <build_export_depend>xacro</build_export_depend>

  <!-- Export for architecture independence -->
  <export>
    <architecture_independent/>
  </export>
</package>

I am just trying to do some basic simulaiton within gazebo. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
